Chromium Android Bundle issue
I have been working with chromium android version 117..0.; i have done some modifications in the ui. error while publishing to play store
now while testing the app build with autoninja -C out/Default chrome_public_apk. the app runs fine. but after building the release build with autoninja -C out/Release Monochrome_public_bundle or autoninja -C out/Release chrome_public_bundle and uploading it to play store. the app crashes on start. i tried extracting the apks from .aab bundle generated and tried installing them using bundletool . the apks install also worked fine. how can i build a signed release build for chromium android?

It might be the Play Store App signing. If it's been activated Play Store will repack the bundle you uploaded while signing it. Since there's no option to opt-out of App signing you can try to create a new project without App signing activation, build your bundles, sign it manually with jarsigner and then upload them to the Play Store.
